# How to solve this D.E?

Tags: differential-equations

I was trying to solve a 2nd order D.E and plot it's solution.

But it shows the following errors.[image]

What is the mistake here?

Also this is my first time using this,so please correct me if my format of asking question is wrong.

Comment: Looks like a capitalization issue to me. You write `Sol = DSolve[...]` but attempt to use `y[x]/.sol[[1]]`. _Mathematica_ treats `Sol` and `sol` as distinctly different variables.

Comment: Please edit your question to replace the image of your code with the code itself, so that readers can copy and run it themselves.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way could be

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ode = y''[x] - 2*y'[x] - 8*y[x] == 0;
sol = y[x] /. First@DSolve[ode, y[x], x];
pars = {{C[1] -> 1/2, C[2] -> 1}, {C[1] -> 1/2, C[2] -> 1/3}, {C[1] -> 2, C[2] -> 3}};
sols = (sol /. #) & /@ pars;

Plot[sols, {x, -2, 2}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Black}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"}, 
 BaseStyle -> 12]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also use Manipulate to change the constants of integrations and see the effect more easily that way. Something like

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ode = y''[x] - 2*y'[x] - 8*y[x] == 0;
sol = y[x] /. First@DSolve[ode, y[x], x];
Manipulate[
 Module[{currentSol},
  currentSol = sol /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2};
  Plot[currentSol, {x, -2, 2}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"}, 
   BaseStyle -> 12]
  ],
 {{c1, 1, "C[1]"}, 0, 10, 1/4, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c2, 1, "C[2]"}, 0, 10, 1/4, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {c1, c2}
 ]
```

[image]

ps. better to post plain text code than images, makes it easier to copy. Also try to avoid UpperCase first letter for names and variables you use.